# IF function with coordinates (Excel)

Tags: excel, if-statement, binary, coordinates

I am looking for a formula that would make my life much easier. I have a table with simple coordinates in the columns and coordinate combinations in the rows. I want Excel to indicate when a coordinate is included in the coordinate pairs. The output should be 0 and 1 (see picture). I was thinking of a If function, but I didn't know how to implement it.

My example has a total of 13 different coordinates, so you can imagine how much work this would be by hand.

Comment: you may use COUNTIF combined witih wildcards

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Formula in Cell B2 is:

`=COUNTIF(B$1;"*"&$A2&"*")`

Notice I'm using mixed references. Just drag to right and to bottom and it will work.

> [COUNTIF
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)
>
> [Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed
> references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that the cell should equal 1, even if the x and y axes are swapped.

Comment: *I forgot to mention that the cell should equal 1* What do you mean? This formula matches with your expected output.

Comment: You are right. I posted a confusing picture in the first place. I want the cells in B2:F7 to equal 1, even if the cells in the column A contain "inverse" values. Thus, if A8 contains 1.0,  B8 should equal 1. Sorry, if it's still confusing, however, I hope it helped clarify

Comment: That's a totally different question because it means you need to reverse the search string. Edit your original question and explain everything properly.